# Hide closed features in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

How can I hide the closed features in the backlog?

[image]

Comment: I can't see a way to do it, looks like there is isn't an option for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change features’ state to close, then these features will be hidden in Features section.

If you want to hide Children workitems (Story) if state is closed, there isn’t this feature available now. I submitted a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16984462-vsts-feature-of-showing-and-hiding-children-workit).

You can show Parents and track stories in Stories section. (The stories will be hidden if state is closed)